# Помогите понять как решать такого типа задачи по численным методам

Tags: математика, матрицы, численные-методы

При каких a и b сходится метод Гаусса-Зейделя для системы с матрицей
A=(a,b,0; b,a,0; 0,0,a) в норме ||.||{1}   ({1} - нижний индекс 1)

Answer (score 0):

Например вот так. Это итерационный метод и к нему применимы все условия сходимости для метода простой итерации.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ещё появились вопросы: 1) что изменится если будет метод Якоби; 2) как влияет норма на решение? Если норма изменится на ||.||{inf} ({inf} - нижний индекс ∞)

Comment: Думаю стоит почитать про метод Якоби. Но он тоже итерационный. Значит для него работают те же соображения, что и для метода простой итерации. Модуль это норма. Заменяете  модуль на другую функцию и получаете новую норму.